# cloud 9 creating 2 workspaces when I try to create 1

Tags: cloud9-ide

I signed up for a (free) c9 account;  verified email address etc.

I selected CREATE NEW WORKSPACE and selected "Ruby on Rails", "Private to the people I invite" (I'm under the impression I get one free Private workspace?), name it "tPRoRD" (abbreviation of the course I'm taking), and select "CREATE"

Expected Behavior:
I hoped to see in the left "MY PROJECTS" pane, adjacent to the default "demo-project", a new project entitled "tPRoRD".

Observed Behavior:
There is a new 'Open and Discoverable' project entitled "tprord";  and a 'greyed-out' project entitled "tPRoRD" which is listed as 'processing'.

When "tPRoRD" is selected, the expected "Start Editing" button is replaced with one entitled "Cancel creation".

I have posted this question on cloud9ide.zendesk.com and have started going back and forth with support - long lags due to time zones.

Has anyone else seen this?

tks!  -rb

Answer (score 0):

(may be) SOLVED:  appears to be fixed on it's own - does anyone know, the little 'lock' icon next to a workspace name indicate the workspace is 'private' vs 'open and discoverable'?​

Comment: Yes, the lock icon next to a workspace name does indicate that it's private. Glad it's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

tks Brady (at cloud 9) and Ruby on Rails instructor Mashrur Hossain for looking into this for me :-)